# not getting same output via user defined function

Tags: c++, return-value, implicit-conversion, return-type

I was trying something in Cpp, but not getting same output when I used the same thing in a user defined function
CODE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum(int x, float y){
    return (x / y);
}
int main(){
    int a;
    float b, c;
    a = 12;
    b = 5;
    c = a / b;
    cout << sum(12, 5) << endl;
    cout << c;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
2
2.4
```

Why am I not getting 2.4 in both the cases?

Comment: Because `int` is not `float`. As a rule of thumb, never mix fixed and floating point arithmetic in the same expression.

Comment: @Lundin oh, I forgot that int return only return integer  sorry for a stupid question

Comment: You did **not** _'used the same thing'_ -- the `sum` function has type `int` whilst the `c` variable is `float`. Converting the result of division to different types does not make 'the same'.

Comment: *I forgot that int return only return integer* -- That's hard to forget it when you wrote the function.  Before posting the question, you should have inspected what you wrote, the output, and figure out quite easily the issue.  If output looks wrong, make sure you've studied the code first before posting the question.  That reduces the chance of posting, as you put it, a "stupid question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of sum is int.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum(int x, float y){ 
    return (x / y);                                //<< this is an int
}
int main(){
    int a;
    float b, c;
    a = 12;
    b = 5;
    c = a / b; << this is a float
    cout << sum(12, 5) << endl;                   //<< prints an int
    cout << c;                                    //<< prints a float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
x / y
```

or

```
a / b
```

has the type float. And in the statement below the value of the expression without any truncation is assigned to the float variable `c`.

```
c = a / b;
```

On the other hand, the returned value of this call

```
sum(12, 5)
```

is converted to the type `int` due to the return type of the function. So the returned value can be truncated.

To get the expected result change the return type of the function to the type `float`

```
float sum(int x, float y){
    return (x / y);
}
```